# How to validate a data row entry

Tags: sql, validation, record

This might seem silly, but in my school lab I am being asked to do two things:

1: add a record to a SALES table using SQL

2: write SQL to validate the record I just entered.

My code for the entry is

```
USE AdventureWorks2012

GO

  INSERT Christopher_Hughes_STORES (StoreCode, Name, Address, City, State, Zip) 

  VALUES ('IT330', 'Test_YourName', '1234 Somewhere Street', 'Here', 'MA', '00333');
```

I have not been able to get an answer from my school on what they mean by asking for code to validate a record. Can someone help clarify what this means?

Comment: It would also be a good idea to add constraints to the table to only accept valid entries. You can do this is you've also created the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it means to just do a select query and make sure that you get the same row back.

In your example, just run a select query on storecode and check if you get the intended result

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking it had to do with constraints and such, but I thought most constraints are created when you first make the table? I hope this is what they wanted, it makes the most sense.

Comment: Ya, and if I've helped you - do mark my answer as correct